# Swagger API generated request fails with 404

Tags: ios, swift, swagger

There are two requests which fail. One `POST` and second `PUT`. Both have one String parameter. Both requests work with Postman. All other Swagger API requests are working.
I figured that 404 from server means that parameter is not sent. 
I sent my custom PUT Alamofire request but inserted String parameter directly into the url and it worked.

Swagger API example:

```
ReportAPI.reportTakenBy(reportId: reportId, completion: { error in
  debugPrint(error)
})
```

My own request that works:

```
let url: String = "https://URL.../reports/TakenBy?reportId=\(reportId)"
let headers:HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization" : accessToken
    ]
Alamofire.request(url, method: RequestMethod.put, parameters: [:], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseData(completionHandler: { response in
            debugPrint(JSON)
  })
```

Now, I debugged AlamofireImplementations.swift and here is the request that is being sent:

> $ curl -i \   -X PUT \    -H "Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" \   -H
>   "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0" \     -H "Authorization: accessToken"
>   \     -H "User-Agent: ProjectName/1.0 (ProjectName; build:1; iOS 10.2.0)
>   Alamofire/4.2.0" \    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
>     -d "reportId=7233A8A2-4DE8-E611-93FF-000D1A214145" \
>     "https://URL.../reports/TakenBy"

Either it's Alamofire that doesn't know to encode PUT parameter, or server that must receive it some other way. Any thoughts?

Comment: The answer is really the type of PUT parameter that was incorrect